# I cant reused data fetched from mysql database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I got one question here. For example I have to fetch data from the db using the provided codes from this tutorial and then after fetch them, read them and use each separately to fetch other data from the db concerning the data chosen.
Consider a simple scenario; lets say I have a db with doctor table (with attributes name, specialty and status). In html view I have a button that when clicked will fetch array list of all specialist from the table excluding duplicates (eg. cardiologists, dentist, dermatologist etc.) and show them to the html list, then after within each specialist group there are list of doctors that is when I click may be cardiologists then I will be able to fetch list of array doctors names from the table where their specialist is cardiology and this should be the same when I click dermatology list and others. And lastly, when I click each name of the doctor fetched the status information from the doctor table will be fetched to see whether there are available or not available. This is like a series of actions.

Please Help how to do so....
Regards.

Below are my current codes

ajax codes to fetch speciality column

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list_specialists").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "fetchSpecialists.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var result_specialists = "<ul>"
                $.each(obj, function() {
                    result_specialists = result_specialists + "<li><a href='#doctors_list' id='list_specific_doctor' class='item-link'><div class='item-content'><div class='item-inner'><div class='item-title'>" + this['speciality'] + "</div></div></div></a></li>";
                });
                result_specialists = result_specialists + "</ul>"
                $("#result_specialists").html(result_specialists);
            }
        });
    });
});</script>
```

php file to fetch data specialists: fetchSpecialists.php

```
<?php
//connect to the mysql
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Could not connect database");
@mysql_select_db('afyamobile', $db) or die("Could not select database");

$sql = @mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT speciality FROM doctors ORDER BY speciality desc");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

//echo result as json
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

ajax file for fetching doctors in the certain speciality group that were fetched with above codes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list_specific_doctor").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "fetchSpecificDoctor.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var result_doctors = "<ul>"
                $.each(obj, function() {
                    result_doctors = result_doctors + "<li><a href='#doctors_list' class='item-link'><div class='item-content'><div class='item-inner'><div class='item-title'>" + this['name'] + "</div></div></div></a></li>";
                });
                result_doctors = result_doctors + "</ul>"
                $("#result_doctors").html(result_doctors);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

its corresponding php file:  fetchSpecificDoctor.php

```
<?php
//connect to the mysql
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Could not connect database");
@mysql_select_db('afyamobile', $db) or die("Could not select database");

$sql = @mysql_query("SELECT name FROM doctors ORDER BY name ASC");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

//echo result as json
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Comment: your list html is invalid. you're giving the same `id` to ALL your records. ids must be unique across the entire document. since you have duplicated IDs, only the **FIRST** entry in your list will ever get found by a `$('#...')` query